# Server sends more than Content-Length of data in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing, vb.net-2010

I have created PDF file programmatically and downloading it. Without loadbalancer it is working fine but when request is sent via load balancer, it is blocking the response due to server sends more than Content-Length. When drop extra data checkbox is checked on the loadbalancer, application starts working and PDF download is working.

My question is what exactly might be causing server to send more than content-length of data? My download code is as follows.

```
 Response.Clear()
 Response.ClearHeaders()
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", CStr(oOutputStream.Length))
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename=abc.pdf")
 Dim statement(CInt(oOutputStream.Length)) As Byte
 oOutputStream.Position = 0
 oOutputStream.Read(statement, 0, CType(oOutputStream.Length, Integer))
 Response.BinaryWrite(statement)

 Response.Flush()
 Response.End()
```

Comment: well if you'd identified the load balancer as the issue, then it's likely to be load balancer which is changing the response, don't you think? Unlikely to be related to your application code.

Comment: @ADyson- Thank you for your reply. Loadbalancer is blocking the response due to content-length and data mismatch. How can this be fixed programmatically?

Comment: you mentioned that changing a setting on the load balancer made it work...which is what makes me think the load balancer is the problem. Is there some reason you can't keep that setting?

Comment: @ADyson- I need to check with production support to keep that settings but want to identify if something is wrong and can be fixed. They want it to be fixed programmatically.

Comment: Have you tried simply not setting the content-length header? I'm not sure it's essential

Comment: I tried to set it to value less than total data to see what happens if these value mismatch but it is working in my development environment. you are right. it seems irrelevant. I don't have load balancer for my dev environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196468/discussion-between-mohan-sharma-and-adyson).

Comment: @MohanSharma - Did you find a good solution to this problem?